# How can I paste special unformatted plain text into Excel using C# and VSTO?

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2010

It's hard to believe this question hasn't been asked or is not possible, but that's what I'm seeing from web searches.

All I would like to do is use VSTO to paste only the unformatted plain text into the active cell range.  Using [Range.PasteSpecial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.pastespecial%28v=office.14%29.aspx) only gives the option to paste values ([among others](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlpastetype%28v=office.14%29.aspx)), but these include formatting.  Is there really no option to paste unformatted text using PasteSpecial?

Is there some other way that anyone has found to do this?  Using macros are not an option in this application.

Here is exactly what I tried:

```
((Excel.Range)Application.Selection).PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues);
```

Comment: xlPasteValues should not include formatting - if you observe that it includes formatting, are you sure there is nothing else wrong?

Comment: Are you sure?  The Excel macro side of it includes a type called "wdPasteText", which is different from paste values.  I think paste values just means that you want to paste the results of any formulas and not the formulas themselves.  I could be wrong, but I'm seeing formats when using PasteValues.  Strange...

Comment: Using the macro recorder, doing a copy-and-paste without formats, shows `xlPasteValues` (which has in fact the integer value -4163). This has nothing to do with formulas. Normally there should be no difference in VSTO when using the same constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange that Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues wouldn't do it for me, but I ended up just doing the following, which works:

```
string textToPaste = (string)Clipboard.GetData("Text");
Clipboard.SetData("Text", textToPaste);
((Excel.Range)Application.Selection).PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues);
```

Hopefully that helps someone else!