# How to insert HTML in Word 2010 Document with VSTO

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I am trying to insert highlighted code (ColorCode-Lib) into a Range of the document. But I do not know how I use the formatted HTML. When I add it via '''Selection.Range.Text = highlightedCode'''; then the plain HTML-Code will be inserted. How can I achieve to insert the formatted HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Formatted HTML shows up when you copy/paste the HTML value into the cell. You can actually do this in VSTO. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673373/how-can-i-paste-special-unformatted-plain-text-into-excel-using-c-sharp-and-vsto)  might help. There is also a macro [here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/02/23/html-in-cells-ii/) that copy/pastes HTML values.

Answer (score 0):

if colourcodelib returns html you have two choice here

1. Save html in a file and try Range.InsertFile([savedfile.html]).
2. You can use Range.InsertXML() but for this you need to find third party library or write your own code to transform html to wordML